# How to filter array and get first value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with many `level` value:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [title] => Technical Leader 
        [level] => 3 
        [ohp_id] => 49 
        [name] => Technical Officer 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [title] => Deputy Chief Officer 
        [level] => 2 
        [ohp_id] => 101 
        [name] => Technical Officer 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [title] => Chief 
        [level] => 2 
        [ohp_id] => 79 
        [name] => Technical Officer 
    ) [3] => Array ( 
        [title] => Deputy 
        [level] => 1 
        [ohp_id] => 97 
        [name] => Technical Officer 
    ) 
)
```

I want filter it in into new array by it's `level` and get only one data for each `level`. Like this one:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [title] => Technical Leader 
        [level] => 3 
        [ohp_id] => 49 
        [name] => Technical Officer 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [title] => Deputy Chief Officer 
        [level] => 2 
        [ohp_id] => 101 
        [name] => Technical Officer 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [title] => Deputy 
        [level] => 1 
        [ohp_id] => 97 
        [name] => Technical Officer 
    ) 
)
```

How to do it? Thanks

Comment: post your desired array and post your code also what you have tried?

Comment: If you want to have 2 times the same `array` `key` in one `array`, then I have to tell you that this is not possible. You can only have this if you rename the `key` to something like `title_1`, `title_2`, ...
But you can do it like you want if you cast the `title` `key` to an `array` with these informations in it.

Comment: Thanks for edit my question @PatrickMlr :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below code :

INPUT :

```
$array = Array ( 
        0 => Array ( 'title' => 'Technical Leader', 
                     'level' => 3, 
                     'ohp_id' => 49,
                     'name' => 'Technical Officer' ), 
        1 => Array ( 'title' => 'Deputy Chief Officer', 
                     'level' => 2, 
                     'ohp_id' => 101,
                     'name' => 'Technical Officer' ), 
        2 => Array ( 'title' => 'Chief', 
                     'level' => 2, 
                     'ohp_id' => 79, 
                     'name' => 'Technical Officer' ), 
        3 => Array ( 'title' => 'Deputy', 
                     'level' => 1, 
                     'ohp_id' => 97, 
                     'name' => 'Technical Officer' ) );


$unique_array = array();
foreach ($array as &$value) {
if (!isset($unique_array[$value['level']]))
    $unique_array[$value['level']] =& $value;
}
$array = array_values($unique_array);
```

OUTPUT :

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [title] => Technical Leader
        [level] => 3
        [ohp_id] => 49
        [name] => Technical Officer
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Deputy Chief Officer
        [level] => 2
        [ohp_id] => 101
        [name] => Technical Officer
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Deputy
        [level] => 1
        [ohp_id] => 97
        [name] => Technical Officer
    )
)
```

Comment: Welcome :) @NikeYulistiaAngreni